# Are there any intuitive/visual ways of detecting interactions between response variables?

Tags: modeling, feature-selection, interaction, exploratory-data-analysis

Say I have a dataset with ~30 variables and I'm trying to make the best lm or glm. What's the best way to do exploratory data analysis to see if any of the variables would produce a good two-way interaction?

I am already knowledgeable about checking to see if *existing* interactions are significant, I'm asking how I should know what

I know that for a certain width of data set you can just do

```
step(lm(Y~(X1+X2+X3+X4)^2, data=mydata))
```

and it will select for two-way interactions, but I'm wondering if there's a more holistic (especially graphical) way of going about it.